# How to change the path at where my secret ends in my application's pod?

Tags: kubernetes, hashicorp-vault, kubernetes-secrets

I am experimenting with HashiCorp Vault. I see that my screts ends at path */vault/secrets* in my application pod after the whole mutating process is done.

But I want my secrets to be at a different location. I tried changing the volume mount directly in the YAML but it did not work.
Kindly suggest.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), ***read about [what's on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)***, and read [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

You need to add an annotation in your Kubernetes manifest :

```
annotations:
  vault.hashicorp.com/secret-volume-path: "wherever/you/want"
```

Described here in the Vault documentation :
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/platform/k8s/injector/annotations#vault-hashicorp-com-secret-volume-path

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the [storage configuration](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/storage#configuration) to tell the vault server where data should be stored.

```
storage "file" {
  path = "/mnt/vault/data"
}
```